# How to stop empty input fields from affecting javascript calculation

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i am trying to add some values. The problem is if one field is empty, the total calculation doesn't show.
How can i solve this problem. all my fields type is number. and i am using vue js

```
grand_total: function(){
                let x = parseInt(this.formData.total_allowance) + parseInt(this.formData.air_fair);
                this.formData.grand_total = x;
                return x;
            }
```

here. if one value is empty,the total doesnt show up

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `parseInt()` you can use `Number()` as this will convert the empty string as `0` where as you will get `NaN` with `parseInt()`:

```
let x = Number(this.formData.total_allowance) + Number(this.formData.air_fair);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this one

```
let x = parseInt(this.formData.total_allowance || 0) + parseInt(this.formData.air_fair || 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the logical 'or' operator in this way:

```
grand_total: function() {
   let x = (parseInt(this.formData.total_allowance) || 0) + (parseInt(this.formData.air_fair) || 0);
   this.formData.grand_total = x;
   return x;
}
```

Comment: If you are processing an unknown number of fields you can simply create a separate function that does this same thing for you and returns the appropriate value.